# .htaccess not rewriting existing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to restrict the access to a certain section of my website by routing all the requests through a php file and checking login and privileges.

I have a folder (`/doc`) with various .html files in it, with mod_rewrite I redirect all of the valid files to a `.php` file in the root (which just prints a test string for now).

This is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` sono
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(wp-content/uploads/.*)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(doc/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^webmail$ "https\:\/\/mywebsite\.mywebsite\.com\:2096\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^doc/(.*)$ /dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The last two lines should rewrite all the URLs of valid files towards the php file.

What happens is for the folder (`mywebsite.com/doc/`) it works and I can't understand why. While for the `.html` files (`mywebsite.com/doc/index.html`) it just shows them without loading the `.php`

Comment: You are probably looking at cached results from earlier attempts ...

Comment: Move up your last rule to place it below `RewriteBase` line

Comment: The ordering the directives is certainly wrong (the "webmail" rule probably isn't doing anything), however, the "last rule" should still _work_ with it being "last". However, it shouldn't be moved to below the `RewriteBase` line... as the comment above states (in French), you should not manually edit the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers since WordPress will overwrite it (at least try to). Are you still having a problem with this? Have you confirmed that it is not a caching issue?

Comment: I would also question why you don't just rewrite every request for `/doc/...` to your script, not just physical files. Your script should already be determining whether the request maps to a downloadable file so should be able to handle 404s etc.

Comment: @MrWhite it's not a caching issue, I've cleaned the cache, tried in incognito mode, other browsers, smartphone. I've moved the RewriteRule up and down, removed the RewriteCond, nothing seems to work. For non-existing files I get the redirect to my .php file, while existing files just get server rightaway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's not a caching issue, I've cleaned the cache, tried in incognito
> mode, other browsers, smartphone. I've moved the RewriteRule up and
> down, removed the RewriteCond, nothing seems to work. For non-existing
> files I get the redirect to my .php file, **while existing files just
> get server rightaway**...

Ignoring the fact you have a file check (ie. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`) in your current directives (so non-existing files should not be directed to your PHP script, unless you are requesting the wrong URL or you removed this condition in testing)...

It looks like you may have a front-end proxy (perhaps Nginx?) for serving static files? This is a relatively common setup, but it means your application server (Apache) is completely bypassed for static file requests, so your directives are not even being processed for direct file requests.

Without adjusting your front-end proxy, a workaround would me to move your files to a different directory, but keep the URL the same, and use Apache to check for the presence of this file instead of the URL that is being requested. (Or, change your URLs.)

For example, you could move the files to an `/actual-files` subdirectory (or somewhere above the document root ideally<sup>***1**</sup>). So, a request for `/doc/myfile.html` is actually referring to `/doc/actual-files/myfile.html`, but since `/doc/myfile.html` doesn't actually exist the front-end proxy doesn't touch it.

```
# Block direct access to `/doc/actual-files/`
RewriteRule ^doc/actual-files - [F]

# Rewrite "/doc/file" requests to download script
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/doc/actual-files/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^doc/(.*)$ /dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, you will *need* to change the ordering of your directives, and you should avoid manually changing the code in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

So, this becomes...

```
# Block direct access to `/doc/actual-files/`
# >>> BUT PROXY SERVER WILL STILL HAVE ACCESS (*1)
RewriteRule ^doc/actual-files - [F]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS here...

# Rewrite "/doc/file" requests to download script
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/doc/actual-files/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^doc/(.*)$ /dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]

# Webmail (website.website.com???)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^webmail$ "https://mywebsite.mywebsite.com:2096/" [R=301,L]

# Prevent certain directories being routed through WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /doc/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` soon
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

*Aside:* You need to ensure that the request is over HTTPS before rewriting to your download script (currently missing from your config).

<sup>***1**</sup> Moving the files to a public subdirectory will still allow the proxy server to access these files directly (if the user finds out the real filesystem path). To avoid this "security issue" you would need to move the files to above the document root - outside of the public HTML space.

Comment: The fact that I probably have this "front-end proxy" makes it useless if I try to hide the files behind a 403 via .htaccess, right?

Comment: @Xruik Yes. As I mentioned above, ideally these files would need to be moved to above the document root. Or, as I initially suggested, move them to a "private" subdirectory - but this relies on security-by-obscurity. (Or, adjust the front-end proxy and make an exception for this subdirectory.)

Comment: @Xruik Have you confirmed there is a front-end proxy? (You can probably tell just by looking at the HTTP response headers for one of these static file requests.)

Comment: Yep "server: nginx" appears in the header, that was it! Thanks!

Comment: Just as a comment for anyone else, I found out that in my hosting (SiteGround) I could deactivate caching (NGINX Direct Delivery).